# How to find out where VCTargetsPath value in Visual Studio 2012 comes from?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

This question was asked many times, but previous answers didn't help me, or I did something wrong.

Anyhow, I have a Visual Studio 2012 solution, which primarily consists of .NET projects, but there is a couple VC++ projects, which fail to load whenever I open the solution. The error for every VC++ project in 'Solution' output is:

> D:\folder\SomeProject.vcxproj : error  : Unable to read the project
>   file "SomeProject.vcxproj". D:\folder\SomeProject.vcxproj(102,3): The
>   imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.props" was not found. Confirm that
>   the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file
>   exists on disk.

The project itself uses `$(VCTargetsPath)` macro to resolve the folder, but it fails for some reason. I tried several solutions, including updating registry and setting environment variables. The only notable change was when I set `VCTargetsPath` environment variable to a valid folder, like `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110` in my case. After reloading a solution I got the following output:

> D:\folder\SomeProject.vcxproj : error  : Unable to read the project
>   file "SomeProject.vcxproj". D:\folder\SomeProject.vcxproj(102,3): The
>   imported project "**D**:\Microsoft.Cpp.props" was not found. Confirm that
>   the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file
>   exists on disk.

I tried running VS repair from the control panel, but it didn't help. I can't reinstall Visual Studio at the moment, because I don't have access to the installation files our company uses. The only working workaround I came up with is building with MSBuild from CLI and setting VCTargetsPath there, like this:

```
$TargetsPath = 'C:\Program%20Files%20(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v110\'
msbuild /v:$Verbosity /m /t:$Target /P:Configuration=$Configuration /P:VCTargetsPath=$TargetsPath /P:TreatWarningsAsErrors=false "$($Solution.FullName)"
```

And solution builds just fine. However, I do need a properly loaded into VS solution, so this workaround solves only some of my problems.

Finally, my question, I guess, would be how to set or override `VCTargetsPath` macro in a Visual Studio 2012 environment? Or how to find out where this macro value is coming from? I'm using Visual Studio 2012 - version 11.0 Update 5.

Comment: Comes from the registry, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions key.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks. My `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions` key is empty. Following some other answers on SO I tried setting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\12.0\11.0\VCTargetsPath` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0\11.0\VCTargetsPath` to the correct path, but with no luck.

Comment: Hmya, when you hack these keys then you'll only ensure that the installer's Repair feature can't fix the problem anymore either.  Stop making it worse, run the installer.